# Macbook Pro (Late 2011) Bootcamp and USB boot questions

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, startup, usb

I have a Macbook Pro with an OWC DataDoubler drive caddy replacing the Superdrive (installed at an Apple premium reseller, when I bought it, so I can still have my warranty).

The main drive slot has an SSD, and the Superdrive slot has the original 750GB hard drive. It all works great, and I have Lion installed on the SSD - blazing fast :) I also have the Superdrive on an external USB enclosure, also works fine.

Problem is, I would like to install Windows on the secondary hard disk. I tried using Bootcamp, but it wouldn't originally let me create the USB install disk (I've overcome that with the tip described [here](http://www.codez4mac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=212&t=61921)) but even if I use the USB Superdrive, I always get the "Boot device not found, press any key" message.

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong? Is it possible to install Windows on a secondary hard drive? How can I avoid the "Boot device not found..." message?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Bootcamp will make a partition and use it for Windows, no? Or what kind of error do you get when you make a partition on the secondary drive?

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

- [How can I install boot camp off a Windows 7 USB flash drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8044/14994)

and  here:

- [Install Bootcamp Windows7 off external USB optical drive on Lion system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22890/14994)

Maybe rEFIt will work for you too, but be aware of this:

- [Installed reFIT on Lion and now I can't login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34465/14994)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this myself on a Mac Pro with 6 internal disks, where I wanted to install BootCamp on a already partitioned disk which isn't the primary disk.

I've made a few notes about it here, but it's rather technical and incomplete: [Install Windows without BootCamp Assistant](http://www.tempel.org/WindowsWithoutBootCampAssistant)

The other "problem" for me is that I can't use the "Startup Disk" System Preferences panel to choose that partition to boot Windows from.

As a work-around, I use two tricks:

1. I hold down the Option key at startup so that the Mac shows me a list of all bootable disks, including the Windows partition.
2. I use a shell script which finds the Windows partition and set it as a one-time startup partition, which is a hint I got from [MacOSHints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110925090353107). The script follows and should be saved as "BootCamp.command":

```
    #! /bin/bash
    diskutil list > /tmp/connecteddrives.txt
    INPUT=/tmp/connecteddrives.txt
    driveid1=$(grep Microsoft "${INPUT}" | awk '{print $8}')
    echo $driveid1
    sudo /usr/sbin/bless --device /dev/$driveid1 --setBoot --legacy --nextonly
    rm /tmp/connecteddrives.txt
    osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to restart'
    exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I used Daemon tools Lite for mac (free) to mount the .iso file and bootcamp let me create the partition, Then I used Winclone 3.5 (not free) to restore an old image I made.

If you don't have an image, you'll have to find a friend with the same model macbook pro you have and see if they will do a fresh windows 7 install that you can then use winclone to copy.